# Summation involving a factorial: $1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n} j!j$

Tags: factorial, sequences-and-series

$$1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n} j!j$$

I want to find a formula for the above and then prove it by induction. The answer according to Wolfram is $(n+1)!-1$, however I have no idea how to get there. Any hints or ideas on how I should tackle this one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a simple induction. Use $(n+1)! = (n+1) \cdot n! = n\cdot n! + n!$.

**Added**: I don't see any better way than to play around with the formula. Rearrange this and you have
$j \cdot j! = (j+1)! - j!$. But then you have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n} j \cdot j! & = \sum_{j=1}^{n} [ (j+1)! - j!] \\
& = [2! - 1!] + [3! - 2!] + \cdots + [n! - (n-1)!] + [(n+1)! - n!]
\end{align*}
and you see that everything cancels, except the terms $- 1!$ from the first summand and $(n+1)!$ from the last summand, hence the sum must be equal to $(n+1)! - 1$.

---

**Edit 2**

Here's the argument:
We want to prove that the following statement $T(n)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
\[
(n+1)! - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} j \cdot j!.
\]
For $n = 1$ we have the statement $T(1)$:
\[
1 = (1+1)! - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{1} j \cdot j! = 1\cdot 1! = 1,
\]
so this is ok. **Assume** that $T(n)$ holds. We want to prove $T(n+1)$:
\[
(n+2)! - 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j \cdot j!.
\]
Start with the right hand side:
\[
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j \cdot j! = (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! + \sum_{j=1}^{n} j \cdot j!
\]
But the last sum is equal to $(n+1)! - 1$ by our **assumption** that $T(n)$ is true, so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j \cdot j! & = (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! + (n+1)! - 1 \\
& = [(n+1) + 1]\cdot(n+1)! - 1 = (n+2) \cdot (n+1)! - 1\\
& = (n+2)! - 1,
\end{align*}
so $T(n+1)$ holds as well.

Comment: Well I havent gotten to the induction part yet. First I need to find a formula for it. I have the answer, but I dont have the steps. I need to know how to do it on my own..

Comment: How did you figure that $j*j!=(j+1)!-j!$ ?

Comment: @mohabitar: I don't really know. I played around with the factorials. From my first line: $(j+1)! = j \cdot j! + j!$ and hence $j \cdot j! = (j+1)! - j!$.

Comment: @Theo so now that we have the formula, I dont get how we prove it by induction. So we say that T(n)=(n+1)! (get rid of the -1 since the original problem had a +1 after the summation). So then we need to show that T(n+1)=(n+2)! ? I dont get how I would prove that..

Comment: @mohabitar: Don't get rid of the $-1$! We have
\begin{align*}
(n+2)! - 1 = (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! + ((n+1)! - 1) = (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! + \cdots
\end{align*}
where you fill in the $\cdots$ using the induction hypothesis!

Comment: See edited top equation. Thats why I got rid of it. But what should my IH be?

Comment: @mohabitar: There is the annoying thing on this site that hitting enter posts a comment, sorry about that, the answer is above.

Comment: Ok I'm really confused. So my IH is T(n)=(n+1)!-1, right? So I need to show that T(n+1)=(n+2)!-1, right? And so what would be the inductive step?

Comment: @mohabitar: You have\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j \cdot j! = (n+1)\cdot n! + \sum_{j=1}^{n} j \cdot j!
\end{align*}
Now use the hypothesis that $T(n) = (n+1)! - 1$, replace the sum on the right with that and use the calculation in my post from 20min ago.

Comment: Ok so then we have (n+1)*n! + (n+1)!-1. (n+1)*n!=(n+1)!. So then we have (n+1)!+(n+1)!-1, which equals 2(n+1)!-1. But that doesnt get me what I wanted. Have I missed something?

Comment: @mohabitar: Sorry, there was a typo in my last post, there should have been $(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!$ instead of $(n+1)n!$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice interpretation of this identity in terms of uniqueness of representation in [factorial base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).  But to answer your comment to Theo Buehler's answer, telescoping sequences are just a thing that you should be aware of and try to look for, and the identity Theo used is actually *equivalent* to what Wolfram told you, so...

Comment: Thanks for that, I was sure you'd have a good explanation for the identity!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a closed form already. If you want to derive it rather than get it from an oracle, Gosper's algorithm will do the job.

Comment: Or rather the instructions were to find a formula. Not sure if that means the same thing..