# Induction Proof for a Sum

Tags: proof-writing, induction

How would I prove

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i(i!) = (n+1)! -1
$$

The base case is n = 1, which is trivial, and using the inductive hypothesis, I get to

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i(i!) = \sum_{i=1}^n i(i!) + (n+1)(n+1)!
$$
which equals
$$
                             (n + 1)! - 1 + (n + 1)(n + 1)! 
$$
I know it has to end up equaling
$$
                           (k + 2)(k + 1)! - 1\\
$$

but I don't know how to make the jump between the two steps. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, $(k+2)(k+1)! = (k+2)!$. Also, note $i(i!) = (i+1)(i!) - i! = (i+1)! - i!$, so instead of induction you can use that this is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by induction: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i \cdot i! = (n+1)!-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26121/proof-by-induction-sum-limits-i-0n-i-cdot-i-n1-1). Note a comment there links to [Summation involving a factorial: $1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n} j!j$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18576/602049) as a possible duplicate, with it having links to other questions about the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use distributive law.

\begin{align}
(n+1)! - 1 + (n + 1)(n + 1)! &= (n+1)! + (n+1)(n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+1)! (1 + (n + 1)) - 1 \\
&= (n+1)!(n+2) -1 
\end{align}