# prove recursive sequence via induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying to prove a recursive sequence via induction. However, this question is quite different from what is being taught from the lecture. The basics of where I can assume a base case $n = 1$, and a case of $n - 1$ or $n + 1$ thereafter. Next, the question may provide like some basic formula like adding different cases to get a fixed formula to the sequence,

However, in this question

> $_ = 0$ where $n = 0$, //may use this as a base case
>
> $_ = _{−1} + $ where $ \ge 1$

What I attempt is to allow the first function $_ = 0$ where $n= 2$ , while the second function $_ = 1$ where $n = 1$, and the third function $_ = 3$ where $n = 2$.

I'm suppose to prove by induction that for all $n \ge 0$, the solution is $_ = (n^2 + n)/2$.

How do I even know how to combine them together without knowing any prior formula to this?

Comment: It is quite illuminating to view the proof as an inductive proof of the uniqueness of the solution of the recurrence, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1883549/242). Further, by telescopy, the solution can also be expressed as $\,\sum_{k=0}^n k\,$ if you already have (inductive) knowledge of such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's review what you know:

1. You know $f_0=0$.
2. You know that $f_n = f_{n-1} + n$ for $n\geq 1$.

You want to prove the claim

$$\forall n: f_n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}.$$

---

A proof by induction of a claim $P(n)$ (in our case, $P(n)$ is $f_n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$) always has two steps:

**Step 1**:

Prove that the claim is true for $n=0$. In other words, you want to prove $P(0)$, in our case you want to prove $f_0=\frac{0^2+0}{2}$, which is fairly easy to prove.

**Step 2**:

Assume that $P(n)$ is true. Now you need to prove $P(n+1)$ is also true. In particular, you want to prove that $$f_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^2 + n+1}{2}$$ while you **assume** that $f_n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ is true.

You can now use the fact that $f_n = f_{n-1} + n$, which means the claim $$f_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^2 + n+1}{2}$$ (which you want to prove) is equivalent to $$f_{n} + n+1 = \frac{(n+1)^2 + n+1}{2}.$$

Now, just use the fact that you already know $f_n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ is true, plug in the value, and you are done.

Comment: at step 2, if we assume n as n + 1, why is fn+1 = ((n+1)^2 + n))/2 instead of ((n+1)^2 + n+1))/2?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Sorry, that was my typo. Of course the $+1$ was missing.

Comment: how do you "jump" from the fact that fn=fn−1+n to fn + n?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan I don't understand the question you just asked. Please use Mathjax to write out the formula you don't understand.

Comment: i have not tried using mathjax before. going to take me sometime to figure it out.

Comment: at the statement where you wrote, use the fact that $$fn=fn−1+n$$ is equivalent to $$fn +n$$. how do you "jump" to that step?

Comment: @Teo I fixed his typo.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Where in my proof did I say that?

Comment: it is after the $$fn+1=((n+1)^2+n+1)/2$$ where you mentioned that $$fn+n=((n+1)^2+n+1)/2$$

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan I have no idea what you are talking about. Please format your formulas correctly. Use the _ sign to get subscripts and ^ to get superscripts. Otherwise it gets unreadable because I don't know if you mean $f_n + 1$ (written as `f_{n} + 1`) or $f_{n+1}$ (written as `f_{n+1}`

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan You are maybe forgetting that $$f_{n+1} = f_{n} + n+1$$ by definition

Answer (score 0):

You found the first few terms correctly. Note:

$\begin{align} 
&f_0 =0, \\
&f_1 =1, \\
&f_2= 1+2, \\
&f_3=1+2+3, \\
&\cdots \\
&f_{n-1}=1+2+\cdots+(n-1) \\
&f_n \ \ \ \ =1+2+\cdots +(n-1)+n = \frac{1+n}{2}\cdot n \\
&f_{n+1} =\underbrace{1+2+\cdots +(n-1)+n}_{f_n}+(n+1) = \frac{1+n}{2}\cdot n+(n+1)= \frac{1+(n+1)}{2}\cdot (n+1).
\end{align}$

Comment: how did you get the ((1+n)/2) x n for fn?

Comment: and how does fn+1 is the same as the solution fn ?

Comment: It is the formula of the sum of $n$ terms of the arithmetic progression. The formula works for $n+1$ too.

Comment: Note that this is *not* a strict proof, and a strict version of this proof would still have to use induction, first of all to prove that $f_n=1+2+\cdots + n$ and second of all to prove (if you didn't yet) that $1+2+\cdots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: @5xum, thanks. However, in the OP $f_n=(n^2+n)/2$ was given and asked to be proved. Here I gave some insight where the formula comes from and $\textit{used}$ induction to prove the formula.

Comment: Oh sure, I understand. I think this is a useful answer, I just added the disclaimer so as not to confuse the OP.