# Prove uniqueness and existence of $\theta$ such that $\theta\left(x,0\right)=x$ and $\theta\left(x,y^{\prime}\right)=\theta\left(x,y\right)^{\prime}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

The domain of consideration is the set of whole numbers, $\mathbb{N}_0$.

The following theorem (see facsimile below) appears in [The Number System, by H.A. Thurston](https://archive.org/details/numbersystem0000unse_r6i5/page/52/mode/2up):

> *3. **Theorem:** There is just one operation $\theta$ such that, for every $x$ and $y,$*
> \begin{align*}
> (i)\text{ }\theta\left(x,0\right)=&x\text{ and}\\
> (ii)\text{ }\theta\left(x,y^{\prime}\right)=&\theta\left(x,y\right)^{\prime}.
> \end{align*}
> Proof: If $\theta$ exists, let $\phi$ be an operation such that
> \begin{align*}
> (iii)\text{ }\phi\left(x,0\right)=&x\text{ for every }x\text{ and}\\
> (iv)\text{ } \phi\left(x,y^{\prime}\right)=&\phi\left(x,y\right)^{\prime}\text{ for every }x\text{ and }y.
> \end{align*}
> Let $M$ be the set of $y$ for which $\phi\left(x,y\right)=\theta\left(x,y\right)$
> for every $x.$ Then $0\in M,$ because $\phi\left(x,0\right)=x=\theta\left(x,0\right)$
> for every $x,$ by $(iii)$ and $(i).$
> \begin{align*}
> \text{If }y\in M\text{, then }\phi\left(x,y^{\prime}\right)= & \phi\left(x,y\right)^{\prime}\text{ by }(iv)\\
> = & \theta\left(x,y\right)^{\prime}\text{ because }y\in M\\
> = & \theta\left(x,y^{\prime}\right)\text{ by }(ii).
> \end{align*}
> Therefore $y^{\prime}\in M.$ Therefore, by [the principle of induction],
> $M$ contains all whole numbers, and so $\phi\left(x,y\right)=\theta\left(x,y\right)$
> for every $x$ and $y;$ that is, there is at *most* one operation satisfying
> $(i)$ and $(ii).$ It remains to prove that there is at *least* one.
> Let $M$ be the set of $x$ for which there is, for each $y,$ a whole
> number $\theta\left(x,y\right)$ such that $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are
> true. If we let
> \begin{align*}
> (v)\text{ }\theta\left(0,y\right)= & y\text{ for every }y,\text{then}\\
> \theta\left(0,0\right)= & 0\text{ by }(v).
> \end{align*}
> Therefore $(i)$ is true when $x=0.$ And
> \begin{align*}
> \theta\left(0,y^{\prime}\right)= & y^{\prime}\text{ by }(v)\\
> = & \theta\left(0,y\right)^{\prime}\text{ by }(v).
> \end{align*}
> Therefore $(ii)$ is true when $x=0.$ Therefore $0\in M.$
> If $z\in M,$let
> \begin{align*}
> (vi)\text{ }\theta\left(z^{\prime},y\right)= & \theta\left(z,y\right)^{\prime}\text{ for every }y.
> \end{align*}
> ($\theta\left(x,y\right)$ is defined, because $z\in M.$) Then
> \begin{align*}
> \theta\left(z^{\prime},0\right)= & \theta\left(z,0\right)^{\prime}\text{ by }(vi)\\
> = & z^{\prime}\text{ by }(i)
> \end{align*}
> because $z\in M.$ Therefore $(i)$ is true when $x=z^{\prime}.$
> And
> \begin{align*}
> \theta\left(z^{\prime},y^{\prime}\right)= & \theta\left(z,y^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}\text{ by }(vi)\\
> = & \theta\left(z,y\right)^{\prime\prime}\text{ by }(ii)\text{ because }z\in M\\
> = & \theta\left(z^{\prime},y\right)^{\prime}\text{ by }(vi).
> \end{align*}
> Therefore $(ii)$ is true when $x=z^{\prime},$ and so $z^{\prime}\in M.$
> Therefore, by [the principal of induction], $M$ contains every
> whole number, and so $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are true for every $x$ and
> $y.$

I contend that to prove the existence of $\theta$ it suffices to show that for arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{N}_0$ the function $\alpha_x\left(y\right)=\theta\left(x,y\right)$ satisfying $(i)$ and $(ii)$ is well defined. So, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}_0$ we define
\begin{align*}
\alpha_x\left(y\right)\in&\mathbb{N}_0,\\
\alpha_x\left(0\right)=&x,\\
\alpha_x\left(y^{\prime}\right)=&\alpha_x\left(y\right)^{\prime}.\\
\end{align*}

The only condition on $x$ is that it is a whole number.  So $\alpha_x$ is defined for $x=0$ and since $x\in\mathbb{N}_0$ then $x^\prime\in\mathbb{N}_0.$ So $\alpha_{x^\prime}$ is equally well defined. Similarly,since $y,\alpha_x\left(y\right)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ then
$y^\prime,\alpha_x\left(y\right)^\prime\in\mathbb{N}_0.$

**Is this sufficient to prove the existence of $\theta$ as defined in Thurston's theorem quoted above?**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand all these usages of prime.  Are $x,y$ both function of let say $t$ and the ' is to be understood as $\frac{d}{dt}$ ? Is $n$ an integer (you speeak about induction) but then proceed to derive it, is it $n(t)$ and arbitrary function then, and the induction is on the iterated derivatives ? Also I don't understand $x=\theta(x,0)=\theta(x,0')=\theta(x,0)'=x'$ what about $x$ is not an exponential ?! A lot of confusion for me on your post.

Comment: This is the recursive definition of addition $\,a_x(y) = x+y,\,$ where $\,n' = n+1,\,$ viz.

$$\begin{align}  a_x(0) &= x\\ a_x(y+1) &= a_x(y)+1\end{align}\qquad$$

Existence and uniqueness of $\,a_x(y)\,$ follows from general results about recursive (inductive) definitions.

Comment: Re: "pedantic overkill" - see the award winning *Monthly* paper by Leon Henkin cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/120586/242) for an excellent introduction to induction and inductive definitions - which makes clear why such rigor is necessary.

Comment: Sorry.  I forget that not everybody is familiar with successor notation.  $x^\prime=x+1$ except we don't know what plus and $1$ are yet.

Comment: @BillDubuque If something is defined for all $x$ proving it inductively seems a bit superfluous.  As far as I know, I'm the person who introduced the subscript notation you are using.

Comment: "Intuitively obvious" is not "rigorous proof". One could also claim that the construction of $\Bbb N$ is obvious, as is the existence and uniqueness of recursively defined functions on $\Bbb N,\ldots $ as is unique prime factorization, etc. But all of those claims require justification, i.e. rigorous mathematical proof. Lacking such proof you are performing magic, not mathematics.

Comment: @BillDubuque My question is not whether the given steps are excessive.  My question is whether they are sufficient.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton  It seems to me you prove that one such function exists (by exhibiting it), not that *there is exactly one* such function as per Thurston's theorem.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio I should have made clear that I am accepting his proof of uniqueness.  I just find his proof of existence to be overly arcane.  I think he did it that way to use the steps in the future.  Perhaps I should study his proof more carefully before criticizing it too harshly.

Comment: @BillDubuque I contend that the statement of the theorem is the statement of its proof by induction on $y$. (i) provides the base case. (ii) provides the induction step with the assumption that $\theta(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}_0.$ Since the only condition on $x$ is that it is a whole number, there is nothing further to say about $x$.

Answer (score -1):

I reject Thurston's entire proof, including the uniqueness part.  Changing the name of the operator proves nothing.  His proposed proof of existence shows that $(v),(vi)$ provide equivalent definitions of $\theta.$ That begs the question.

Instead I proceed as follows: $\theta$ can be viewed as a three-place relation of whole numbers.  Thus it can be treated as the set

$$\vartheta=\left\{\langle{x,y,z}\rangle\backepsilon z=\theta\left(x,y\right)\right\}\subset\mathbb{N}_0^3$$

generated recursively using $(i),(ii).$
That $\vartheta\neq\mathbb{N}_0^3$ follows from $\langle{0^\prime,0,0}\rangle\notin\vartheta.$

To show that this generation deterministically produces exactly $\vartheta,$ we could use induction on $x$ with each step being induction on $y.$  However, since $(i),(ii)$ are defined identically for all $x,$ there is no need for induction on $x$. Thus we consider the case of an arbitrarily chosen $x.$

Assume $x\in\mathbb{N}_0.$ Rule $(i)$ provides the base case. Assume $y=0.$

$$(i)\land y=0\implies\langle x,y,x\rangle\in\vartheta$$

So $\theta$ is uniquely determined for each $x$ and $y=0.$

Rule $(ii)$ provides the $y\mapsto y^\prime$ induction step. For arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{N}_0$ assume $z=\theta\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is uniquely determined.

$$(ii)\land\langle x,y,z\rangle\in\vartheta\implies\langle x,y^\prime,z^\prime\rangle\in\vartheta$$

Uniqueness and closure follow from the **defined** uniqueness and closure of the successor of a whole number.

Thus we have shown that for all $x$ we have that $\theta\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is uniquely determined for $y=0,$ and if $\theta\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is uniquely determined for $y\in\mathbb{N}_0$ then $\theta\left(x,y^\prime\right)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is uniquely determined.

We conclude that $\theta:\mathbb{N}_0\times\mathbb{N}_0\mapsto\mathbb{N}_0$ is well defined.  That is, $\theta$ gives exactly one whole number for each pair of whole number arguments.

---

To regain Thurston's implicit results that $\theta\left(0,y\right)=y$ and $\theta\left(x^\prime,y\right)=\theta\left(x,y^\prime\right)$ we proceed as follows:

By $(i)$ we have $y=0\implies\theta\left(0,y\right)=y=0.$

By $(ii)$ and the induction hypothesis that for arbitrary $y$ we assume $\theta\left(0,y\right)=y$ we obtain $\theta\left(0,y^\prime\right)=y^\prime.$

So we have produced Thurston's $(v)$

$$y\in\mathbb{N}_0\implies\theta\left(0,y\right)=y.$$

---

We now show 
$$\theta\left(x^\prime,y\right)=\theta\left(x,y^\prime\right).$$

Assume $x$ is arbitrary and $y=0.$ By $(i)$ we have the first two equalities in
$$y=0\implies\theta\left(x^\prime,y\right)
=x^\prime=\theta\left(x,y\right)^\prime
=\theta\left(x,y^\prime\right).$$  The third equality follows from $(ii).$

Assume that for arbitrary $x,y$ we have
$$\theta\left(x^\prime,y\right)=\theta\left(x,y^\prime\right).$$

The induction step $y\mapsto y^\prime$ is as follows: Using $(ii)$ to obtain the first and third equalities, and our assumption to obtain the second, we have
$$\theta\left(x^\prime,y^\prime\right)
=\theta\left(x^\prime,y\right)^\prime
=\theta\left(x,y^\prime\right)^\prime
=\theta\left(x,y^{\prime\prime}\right).$$

Using $(ii)$ we recover Thurston's $(vi)$

$$\theta\left(x^\prime,y\right)=\theta\left(x,y\right)^\prime.$$